# Dynamics CRM 2011 Advanced find - Filter for Name with spaces in between

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

The problem is simple, I have some contacts in CRM whose First names have Middle Initials attached to them (faulty imports I m guessing from previous systems)

For e.g.

```
 FirstName   MiddleName   LastName

 John F.                   Kennedy
```

instead of

```
 FirstName   MiddleName   LastName

 John          F          Kennedy
```

so I went on to create a process to update the middle name but I couldn't nail down the filtering process for space.
In advanced view I tried both

`Firstname contains [ ] , Firstname contains ' '`

but no hits, I wonder what the right search string would be in this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Wildcard Characters:

`Firstname contains * *`